# Freeradius Not Starting . Error "Unable to open file "/etc/freeradius/3.0/radiusd.conf": No such file or directory"

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, freeradius

So i mistakenly deleted the freeradius directory in "/etc/freeradius/3.0" on Ubuntu 20.04. After re-installing version 3.0.23 from tar file in freeradius website. I noticed directory structure is totally different and main files are in **"[/etc/freeradius/installation directory/etc/raddb]"** instead of just **"/etc/freeradius/3.0"**. But i can still run freeradius in debugmode and all but after doing some configurations on clients.conf file and restarting the server i get the error **Job for freeradius.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status freeradius.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.** and when i run the **journalctl -xe** command.I get the error.
[freeradius error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfYUR.png) . But as i can see its looking for the radiusd.conf file in the wrong directory structure even thou i compiled and installed from source tar file.

Comment: What if you copy and paste the exact `radius.conf` to `/etc/freeradius/3.0/` folder. Does it worked? If you don't have it, you can refers to freeradius's github https://github.com/enckse/freeradius/blob/master/radiusd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Try this site:
[https://phoenixnap.com/kb/uninstall-packages-programs-ubuntu#:~:text=To%20remove%20an%20application%2C%20highlight%20it%20%3E%20right-click,to%20Remove%20Package%20on%20Ubuntu%20From%20Command%20Line](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/uninstall-packages-programs-ubuntu#:%7E:text=To%20remove%20an%20application%2C%20highlight%20it%20%3E%20right-click,to%20Remove%20Package%20on%20Ubuntu%20From%20Command%20Line)

I did the
dpkg-query -l | grep radius

Returned with:
rc  freeradius                                 3.0.20+dfsg-3build1                        amd64        high-performance and highly configurable RADIUS server
rc  freeradius-common                          3.0.20+dfsg-3build1                        all          FreeRADIUS common files
rc  freeradius-config                          3.0.20+dfsg-3build1                        amd64        FreeRADIUS default config files

Then for each of the three I did
apt-get remove --purge freeradius
apt-get remove --purge freeradius-common
apt-get remove --purge freeradius-config

Then
apt install freeradius freeradius-mysql freeradius-utils

And the default directories returned in the /etc/freeradius/3.0/ directory.

Happy I am!